# How can I make a 301 redirect from an old page asp to a new page php?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've changed domain and now I want to do 301 redirects of the main categories on the old site into the news categories

Comment: I want to write redirect in htaccses .file

Answer (score 0):

redirect:

```
Redirect 301 http://yourolddomain.com/olddirectory/oldfile.asp http://yournewdomain.com/newdirectory/newfile.php
```

If you have an old domain, you need to put this file in the root directory of your old domain and it will send it to the new domain.

Comment: The old domain is on the old server and not in use so there needs to be a relative redirect to the new domain from the new server should actually redirect from - /old page.asp to /new page.php  what is the corecct syntex to this redirect?

Comment: you can't redirect a domain that is not yours... imagine people redirecting google

Comment: You can buy back your old domain with your new server and then you will be able to use the redirect I have written above.  @eti Even if you don't have the files anymore